# Visual C++ MFC app tooltip suddenly throws assertion error (m_hWnd = Null) after porting to VS2017 from VS6

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

A library called ToolTip2 was used to create a tooltip in a visual c++ application. It was done on Visual Studio 6 (!), however.

I had the task of migrating the project to Visual Studio 2017, and all works fine, except for the tooltips. They throw an assertion error with `m_hWnd = NULL`, which I confirmed during debugging.

I am no Microsoft expert, but from what I understand, `m_hWnd` gets assigned during the `CreateEx` method, which looks like this in the tooltip library:

```
bSuccess = CreateEx(NULL, NULL, NULL, WS_POPUP | WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS,
                         rectInitialiSize, m-pParentWnd, NULL, NULL);
```

Now, I noticed that `bSuccess` is not actually modified. meaning, if I set it `TRUE` before the aforementioned function, it stays `TRUE`. Same for `FALSE`.

The result is that during the later show() function, the first line fails the assertion at:

```
ASSERT(m_hWnd != NULL);
```

If I am correct in that `m_hWnd` is assigned at `CreateEx()`, then it leads me to believe that this makes sense and that `CreateEx()` is somehow not working anymore.

Like I said, it all worked before migration, so I assume it is some internal MFC stuff that has changed.

Comment: This isn't really enough info to go on.  From what class does CreateEx come from?  From what class is it derived?  The "internal stuff" is the key. 
 Have you tried stepping into the call in the debugger, seeing where/when m_hWnd gets assigned? What is it returning?

Every single MFC class derived from CWnd has an m_hWnd.    If the m_hWnd gets created successfully, it will be non-null.  If you want to hook into when it is destroyed, override the PostNcDestroy function and put a breakpoint in the implementation.

Comment: I think `NULL` is not a valid value for a second parameter of `CreateEx`, that is for a class name.

Comment: I know I gave very limited info. I just reckon that if it worked initially, I have no reason to suspect the library or the MFC class internals. I was first wondering if some fundamental change happened in the newer VS that somehow changes how CreateEx should be called?

Comment: Yes @VTT I also noticed that in the docs. My problem persisted after correcting that, however.